# Integrate Google Sign-On with an ASP.NET 1.1 Framework Project?

Tags: asp.net, .net, sign

I have a fairly large project built using ASP.NET website written with .NET 1.1 Framework. Does anyone know if it's possible to allow users to sign-on using their existing Google Account's without a major rewrite?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Then come back and revisit your question. As it stands, it is impossible to give you a relativly helpful answer except Yes, No, Maybe and 42.

Comment: google single sign on uses saml right? perhaps you should start there. as for *no major rewrite*, i doubt it. https://support.google.com/a/answer/60224?hl=en

Comment: Keep in mind that ASP.Net 1.1 is completely unsupported by Microsoft now on any OS that is currently in support.